# Angular 6: Template parse errors: 'component' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to use a component selector in another component but it shows an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'registryTable' is not a known element:
1. If 'registryTable' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("[ERROR ->]<registryTable></registryTable>"):
```

I have tried adding it to `app.module.ts` but it still throws that error.

here is part of code I am using.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RegisteryComponent } from './registery/registery.component';
import { RegisteryTableComponent } from './registery/registry-table/registery-table.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RegisteryComponent,
        RegisteryTableComponent
    ],
    imports: [
    ...
    ],
    exports: [
        CdkTableModule,
        CdkTreeModule
    ],
    providers: [...],

    entryComponents: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**registry.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { RegisteryTableComponent } from './registry-table/registery-table.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-registery',
    template: '<registry-table></registry-table>',
    styleUrls: ['./registery.component.scss']
})
export class RegisteryComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(RegisteryTableComponent) registeryTable: RegisteryTableComponent;

    constructor() { }


    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**registry-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'registery-table',
    templateUrl: './registery-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./registery-table.component.scss']
})
export class RegisteryTableComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

What I have already tried:

1. Adding `RegisteryTableComponent` to `entryComponents` in `app.module.ts`.
2. Added `RegisteryTableComponent` to `exports` array in `app.module.ts`

I have tried most of the solutions found for similar error but none of them worked for me.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This seems that your registry table component is in another module. Are you using 2 or more modules in your project?

Comment: No, its not in another module, there are multiple modules but `registryTableComponent` is not part of any module, instead it is part of root module.

Comment: You made a typo mistake while rendering selector

Comment: @SnehaPawar yes it was typo, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've typo'd the selector change `registery-table` to `registry-table`

Comment: Can't believe it was a spelling issue.

Comment: Happens to the best of us buddy, one always thinks it's something more complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

Change selector in registry-table.component.ts
from 'registery-table' to this 'registry-table'